# What does "up" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

In the movie "The Batman" there is a scene in which the Batman speaks about the state of the Gotham City.
"Murder, robberies, assault. Two years later, they're all **up**."

Merriam Webster def for **up**
b: being above a former or normal level (as of quantity or intensity)
"*attendance is up"
"the wind is up*"

Is this the correct meaning for this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that the number of each of those crimes has increased over the last two years.

It is an ellipsis, meaning that a word or phrase is implied rather than explicitly specified. In spoken American English, ellipsis is quite common.

> They're all up

is an ellipsis for

> Their numbers are all up

So that is the correct meaning of up, but it relates to a noun not explicitly specified, namely "numbers.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but would the sentence make sense with the definitions from Merriam Webster I provided?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly the meaning intended. It just was obscured because what was quantitatively increased (the number of crimes) was not specified. I understand your concern: how do you possibly increase a murder.